# É possivel realizar rolagem no git bash?

Tags: git, windows-8

Acabei de instalar o `git` e optei por instalar o `git bash` (ferramenta de linha de comando) junto, pra usar todos os comandos do `git` por ele. Entretanto, reparei que a rolagem do mouse não funciona nesse prompt. Alguém já passou por isso? Estou usando o Windows 8.

Answer (score 2):

Acredito que o que você está tentando fazer é o que este post [aqui](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/keyboard-ninja-scrolling-the-windows-command-prompt-with-only-the-keyboard/) explica.

Abaixo copia do texto original do site:

> The Windows command prompt (cmd.exe) has always been known for being
>   underpowered compared to Linux, but have you ever noticed that to view
>   the output of a long command you have to resort to the mouse to
>   scroll?
>
> You can easily scroll with just the keyboard, but to get into the
>   “Scroll Mode” you’ll have to use a 4-key combination that reminds me
>   of cheat codes on old nintendo games… Up, Up, Down, Down…
>
> Press Alt+Space together, and then E, then L
>
> This will put the command prompt into “Scroll” mode, where you can use
>   the Page Up/Down keys as well as the arrow keys.
>
> To get out of this mode, you can hit the Esc or Enter keys.

Comment: Eu fiz isso, mas habilitou o scroll pelo teclado apenas, o scroll do mouse ainda não funciona.

Comment: Ok, então você pode tentar seguir as instruções deste [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9155896/how-to-mouse-scroll-with-git-bash) do stackoverflow em inglês, infelizmente não uso o windows para te ajudar melhor.

Comment: Sem chance também, o ruindows não funciona! Mas obrigada pelas repostas.

Comment: Links não são respostas. O que acontece se as referencias sairem do ar? Poste o trecho que interessa do site/post.

Comment: Pronto fotanus, desculpe pela falta de cuidado com o contéudo é que no momento estava com pressa, já o segundo link é referente ao stackoverflow, há necessidade de referenciar conteúdo da mesma forma?

Comment: @LuizFilipe +1 por arrumar a resposta. Eu imagino que para respostas do stackoverflow em inglês, o conteudo deve ser copiado, mas não se o link for para o stackoverflow em português. Porém não é o que a comunidade tem apoiado, como pode ver [nessa pergunta do meta](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/480/devemos-indicar-fonte-das-wiki-de-tags-quando-ela-vem-da-tag-do-so-em-ingles). Porém tem poucos votos ainda para ser considerado um padrão, então sinta-se livre para contribuir.

Answer (score 1):

Habilite o modo *Quick Edit*.

Em *Properties*, na aba *Option* -> *Edit Option* -> marque a opção *Quick Edit* e dê OK.

(solução encontrada em um [post do Stack Overflow em inglês](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9155896/how-to-mouse-scroll-with-git-bash), teste e diga-nos se deu certo).

Comment: Isso não funcionou também!

Comment: Já havia dado essa alternativa.

Answer (score 0):

Utilize o *[ConEmu](http://sourceforge.net/projects/conemu/)*, alternativa open-source ao Command Prompt e Power Shell.

Answer (score 0):

Sob o GitBash, Clique com o botão direito do mouse e selecione **Barra de rolagem**.

[image: Imagem ilustrativa]

Answer (score -1):

Quando abrir o Git Bash clique com o botão direito do mouse e escolhar scroll.

Tente pegar a versão de 32 bit. Elas funcionam melhor no windows 8.